Join return empty but subquery doesn't
I have 2 tables:
Invoice
CustomerInvoiceID - PK
RecordLocator - Text
createdDate - date

SimplifiedInvoice
CustomerInvoiceID - PK / FK Invoices
CountryCode - text
VatPercentage - number
SubtotalAmount - number
TotalAmount - number

If I run the following query:
select  
    si.CountryCode, 
    si.RecordLocator, 
    si.CustomerInvoiceID, 
    i.CreatedDate,  
    i.VatPercentage, 
    si.SubTotalAmount, 
    si.TotalAmount
from
    SimpliedInvoice si , invoice i 
where 
    si.CustomerInvoiceID = i.CustomerInvoiceID
    and si.CountryCode = 'GR'

My result is an empty dataset.
But if I run this query:
select * 
from SimpliedInvoice
where CustomerInvoiceID in (select CustomerInvoiceID 
                            from Invoice 
                            where CountryCode = 'GR')

I get plenty of data.
I am not able to see why, any idea?

Just an aside, you should really avoid the old style joins.   Always best to use an EXPLICIT JOIN

Definitely sort out your join syntax as John says.

Well, in your first query, you check the SimplifiedInvoice table (alias si) for the CountryCode = 'GR' -
where 
    ....
    and si.CountryCode = 'GR'
        *********************

But in your second query, you're testing the Invoice table in the subquery for that same country code:
where CustomerInvoiceID in (select CustomerInvoiceID 
                            from Invoice 
                                 *******  
                            where CountryCode = 'GR')
                                  ******************

So change your first query to:
select  
    si.CountryCode, 
    si.RecordLocator, 
    si.CustomerInvoiceID, 
    i.CreatedDate,  
    i.VatPercentage, 
    si.SubTotalAmount, 
    si.TotalAmount
from
    SimpliedInvoice si 
inner join
    invoice i on si.CustomerInvoiceID = i.CustomerInvoiceID
where 
    i.CountryCode = 'GR'

and you should get the same set of data returned

In the first query the CountryCode is coming from the SimpliedInvoice table; in the second query the CountryCode is coming from the Invoice table, so they are not querying the same data. This suggests data in the SimpliedInvoice that may be out of sync with the Invoice table, assuming the intent was to keep them in sync.
